# inverse relation in a vector lattice

Tags: functional-analysis, lattice-orders, vector-lattices

Let $X$ be a vector lattice endowed with an ordering $\leq$. If for some operator $\phi:X_+\rightarrow X$ and $m,M\in X$, we have 
$$m\leq \phi(x)\leq M,\quad x\in X_+. $$
 What would be the bound for $\phi^{-1}$? Or if it's bounded even.

Comment: $\phi$ is not an operator, since $X_+$ is not a linear space

Comment: $\phi$ may not be surjective, so $\phi^{-1}$ is not always well defined

Comment: yes, but whenever it exists.  is there any corresponding relation for boundedness?